# How to fix a "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to write a virtual assistant in python, and i got this error it says "IndentationError: expected an indented block" I'm using python 3.6.9 and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

So okay, Here is the line i got the error

```
if('date' in text):
    get_date = getDate()
    response = response + ' '+get_date

 File "testassis.py", line 136
get_date = getDate()
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: Indention looks correct, the problem likely exists in a line above the if statement you provided. Can you please edit your question and provide the code immediately proceeding what you have provided.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `cat -t <your_file>` (10 lines around the error message should do)?

Comment: Indentation must be off relative to rest of the file: Could be Tab vs space or 3 spaces instead of 4 spaces elsewhere etc.